# Issues in connecting to Neo4j from linux

Tags: neo4j

Trying to connect to Neo4j from java I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /data/graph.db
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:323)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
>   at .....
>
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
>   Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@4514ba77' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:300)
>
> ```
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
> ```
>
> 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@2c86c977' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:165)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
>
> ```
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No schema index provider org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider
> ```
>
> found. Kernel extensions available on classpath:
>
> Class path entries:   /...../java/....xyz.jar
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider$2.select(SchemaIndexProvider.java:136)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider$2.select(SchemaIndexProvider.java:128)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.resolveDependency(KernelExtensions.java:207)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DependencyResolverImpl.resolveDependency(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1403)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:311)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
>           ... 12 more

I am using Ne04j-2.0.0-M05 version, running the java code under Java 7 in a linux machine. The same jar files and java code works good though in a windows machine. The web admin interface works well (hence path to db may not be a issue since I ve given the same path in org.neo4j.server.database.location and org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri),

The java code I used to connect is :

```
String dbpath = "/NEO4J_HOME/data/graph.db/";
graphdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(dbpath);
```

Can you tell what might cause the **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No schema index provider org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider found**

Comment: Does your user have r/w permissions on `NEO4J_HOME`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep Neo4j related jars seperate, i.e do not bundle them inside the jar you create. Instead just make use of class path option to point Neo4j libraries in run time.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're lacking [neo4j-lucene-index](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-lucene-index) on your classpath. If that hint does not help provide a list of jars being on the classpath.

Comment: Hi , yes that is the problem, I built my own jar infact which causes the problem, have to keep individual jars of Neo4j as such or merge the METAINF contents of jars is the response I got in a google group.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, and finally fount it's the different version of neo4j and neo4j-lucene-index which caused the error. They need to keep in the same version. Still not sure which version of lucene it depends on, but 3.6.2 can survive the compile. Thanks Stefan. It's hard to find the latest version of everything neo4j depends on.

```
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:2.0.0-RC1"
compile "org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:3.6.2"
compile "org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:2.0.0-RC1"
```

This fixed my error.