# Neo4j not starts

Tags: java, neo4j, lucene

I'm trying to run Neo4j database with java but it gives me the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/matteo/neo4j-community-2.2.2/data/graph.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:334)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
    at Getter.main(Getter.java:46)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@2e9a2123' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:330)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@1c3c1d18' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.init(KernelExtensions.java:74)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_36
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.<clinit>(LuceneDataSource.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.init(LuceneKernelExtension.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483)
    ... 12 more
```

Where is the problem??
Thank you very much!
Matteo

Comment: Similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589767/issues-in-connecting-to-neo4j-from-linux

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running embedded Neo4j this looks like you're missing `lucene-core-3.6.2.jar` on your classpath.

Best practice is to use a build system supporting transitive dependencies like gradle or maven. For those the most easy this is have a dependency on `neo4j-community` artifact, e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j/2.2.5. This will pull in all other required jars.